# Programmatically Add ButtonColumn to GridView From DataTable

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, datatable

I have a problem adding a column with buttons in GridView.

As you see from the code below, the data source from teh GridView is a DataTable. I need to add an additional column to the table with a button.

From the code below, I get an error message saying:

> Value of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewButtonColumn' cannot
>   be converted to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlField'.

```
    Dim dt_AllGroupsSetUp2 As New DataTable()
    dt_AllGroupsSetUp2.Columns.Add("Name", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    dt_AllGroupsSetUp2.Columns.Add("Age", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    dt_AllGroupsSetUp2.Columns.Add("Hight", Type.GetType("System.String"))

    For i As Integer = 0 To 7
        dt_AllGroupsSetUp2.Rows.Add()
        dt_AllGroupsSetUp2.Rows(i)(0) = "John"
        dt_AllGroupsSetUp2.Rows(i)(1) = 10
        dt_AllGroupsSetUp2.Rows(i)(2) = 70
    Next

    GV_DataByGroupAct.DataSource = dt_AllGroupsSetUp2
    Dim buttonColumn As New DataGridViewButtonColumn
    buttonColumn.Name = "Button"
    GV_DataByGroupAct.Columns.Add(buttonColumn)
    GV_DataByGroupAct.DataBind()
```

I tried the folling also but returned the following error: 'New' cannot be used on a class that is declared 'MustInherit'.

```
    GV_DataByGroupAct.DataSource = dt_AllGroupsSetUp2
    Dim buttonColumn As New DataControlField
    GV_DataByGroupAct.Columns.Add(buttonColumn)
    GV_DataByGroupAct.DataBind()
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the code behind use this before binding data to GridView (but it's c#):

```
GV_DataByGroupAct.Columns.Add(new ButtonField() { Text = "Button" });
```

Or you could prepare the GridView with the button field

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GV_DataByGroupAct" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Age" HeaderText="Age" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Hight" HeaderText="Hight" />
            <asp:ButtonField Text="Button" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

after bind you will have this result:

[image]

Comment: I've modified the code to use the button field, but the new column does not appear. Code: >> GV_DataByGroupAct.DataSource = dt_AllGroupsSetUp2 >> Dim buttonColumn As New ButtonField >> GV_DataByGroupAct.Columns.Add(ButtonColumn) >> GV_DataByGroupAct.DataBind()

Comment: Try to add the ButtonColumn first.

Comment: And how do I catch its click event?
(Thanks a lot in advance)

Comment: For example:
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Name") %>' CommandName="Button1Click" OnCommand="Button1_Command"/>

and in the code behind:
    protected void Button1_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
        {
            // -- DO SOMETHING -- info in e.CommandName and e.CommandArgument
        }

Answer (score 1):

I was really complicating things. Thanks Jenda, it is easier to prepare the grid view. The following workds if it helps someone:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GV_DataByGroupAct" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Age" HeaderText="Age" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Hight" HeaderText="Hight" />
        <asp:ButtonField Text="Button" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code:

```
Dim dt_AllGroupsSetUp2 As New DataTable()
dt_AllGroupsSetUp2.Columns.Add("Name", Type.GetType("System.String"))
dt_AllGroupsSetUp2.Columns.Add("Age", Type.GetType("System.String"))
dt_AllGroupsSetUp2.Columns.Add("Hight", Type.GetType("System.String"))

For i As Integer = 0 To 7
    dt_AllGroupsSetUp2.Rows.Add()
    dt_AllGroupsSetUp2.Rows(i)(0) = "John"
    dt_AllGroupsSetUp2.Rows(i)(1) = 10
    dt_AllGroupsSetUp2.Rows(i)(2) = 70
Next

    GV_DataByGroupAct.DataSource = dt_AllGroupsSetUp2
    GV_DataByGroupAct.DataBind()
```

Answer (score 0):

DataGridViewButtonColumn is intended to be used in DataGridView control.

With GridView you can use [ButtonField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.buttonfield.aspx).