# Getting and error I cannot fix when trying to add a button column

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, datagridview, datagridviewbuttoncolumn

I am having trouble fixing an error that I keep getting when I try to add a button column to my table.  The error is: **Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewButtonColumn' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlField'**

It is basically saying that I cannot use the local variable 'btn' in the line

```
        gridViewStudent.Columns.Add(btn);
```

in the following code:

```
        gridViewStudent.DataSource = table;
        gridViewStudent.DataBind();

        DataGridViewButtonColumn btn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
        gridViewStudent.Columns.Add(btn);
        btn.HeaderText = "Click Data";
        btn.Text = "Click Here";
        btn.Name = "btn";
        btn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
```

Comment: As the error is trying to tell you, you're trying to mix two different namespaces.  Don't do that.

Comment: What makes you think you can add a `Windows.Forms` control to a ASP.NET form?

Comment: I'm trying to follow some other code that I found online here when trying to add a button column, and they all seem to follow the same structure, so I am not exactly sure what is different.  Do i need to post more of my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`DataGridViewButtonColumn`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewbuttoncolumn(v=vs.110).aspx) intended to use with WinForms' `DataGridView` control. In Web Forms context you may use `ButtonField` instead:

```
var btn = new ButtonField();
btn.HeaderText = "Click Data";
btn.Text = "Click Here";

gridViewStudent.Columns.Add(btn);
```

Since there is no `Name` and `UseColumnTextForButtonValue` properties present for `ButtonField` control, their assignments are just omitted.

Alternatively you can use prepared `asp:ButtonField` inside `Columns` section in ASPX page:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gridViewStudent" ... />
    <Columns>
        <%-- other fields --%>
        <asp:ButtonField HeaderText="Click Data" Text="Click Here" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Similar issue:

[Programmatically Add ButtonColumn to GridView From DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18636376/programmatically-add-buttoncolumn-to-gridview-from-datatable)

Comment: I have made this change and the build is now successful, but the buttons and column header still do not show up.  Is there perhaps a specific place where this code should be?  I currently have it after I data bind the data table.

Comment: That's probably more suitable to create a follow-up question. Post your fixed gridview markup & code behind on that new question and put a link to this question to see your effort.